# tailwindcss width and height property not working for images(Logo as .svg)

Tags: tailwind-css

I am just learning tailwindcss and now I'm trying an example on [tailwindcss.com](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first) in VScode but the result isn't the same. Logo size larger than what It is specified by `h-12 w-12` !

I tried the exactly copied codes from there and I only changed the source property for `img`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-6 max-w-sm mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl shadow-lg flex items-center space-x-4">
        <div class="shrink-0">
          <img class="h-12 w-12" src="/F:\Programs\Programs\ICONS\Icon-Mix-Pack\Ico/reg.ico" alt="ChitChat Logo">
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="text-xl font-medium text-black">ChitChat</div>
          <p class="text-slate-500">You have a new message!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result was:
[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBCJ1.jpg)
But must be:
[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeFpD.jpg)
I even tried this one which I saw on similar topics but nothing changed:

```
<img class="h-{10px} w-{10px}" src="/F:\Programs\Programs\ICONS\Icon-Mix-Pack\Ico/reg.ico" alt="ChitChat Logo">
```

What can I do? Should I use [adding custom styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) ? I read that topic but I am still not sure how to define width and height property in tailwind.config.js!! Please help!

Comment: Consider checking you have run a Tailwind compilation and linked the output CSS in the HTML file. Also check the file the HTML code is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Answer (score 0):

- Assign the `h-12`and `w-12` to the parent `div` for the `img` element, and then
- assign a class of `w-full` to the image element to ensure it takes
  the width of the parent `div` - which, in this case, will be `w-12`.

Answer (score 0):

Uh!
After that I even had a worse experience that even colors like pink,red,yellow,... weren't working for me!

The problem solved after I start a new project as same as what is said on [tailwindcss.com](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) installation tutorial. I did exactly the same. the same directories and I used "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch" in terminal this time and Everything works fine.

Apparently the reason was errors during build or something like that! I'm not 100% sure.

My previous setting was as you can see in these pictures: [tailwind.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TARQ0.png) [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUWdU.png)